# Alfresco Move/Copy Dataset

Tags: dataset, record, alfresco, rule, alfresco-share

I'm experiencing an issue with Alfresco, or maybe it isn't really an issue, but I just don't know how to do it.... I installed Alfresco Community 4.2.f and the Record Management AMP File to create custom Metadata for example: Checked (Boolean) which appears if I declare a File as a dataset and I can set this boolean  via a selection button which is really what I wanted... So my problem is:

I've created a rule to copy or move all files that has this metadata checked as true.. but the problem is that Alfresco can't move my dataset to another folder... why?

EDIT: When I try to move the dataset I get this message: `03220047 Zugriff verweigert. Sie verfügen nicht über die Berechtigungen, um diesen Vorgang durchzuführen.` (german for: Access is denied. You do not have the permissions to perform this operation.  )

Best regards
Dave

Comment: Looks like the other folder where you are trying to move there you do not have permission. Are you trying it with admin account?

Comment: Yes it is the Admin account and I have all permissions in both folders.

Comment: Any other errors in log files?

Comment: no there aren't any errors in the log files